# Change Image Src from child pop doesn't affect code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, webforms, popup

I have Parent Web Form where I have image.
I have although link in form when I click I open new pop up contains another Page like that :

```
        function openPopUp() {
        popup = window.open("/CropImage.aspx", "Popup", "width=700,height=700");
        popup.focus();
    }
```

in the child pop up page I choose image and pass it again to parent Page by setting parent page image src.

```
opener.document.getElementById("tile_Image").src = "/Path/imageName.jpg" ;
```

the parent page image changed already but when I access it from code behind I find no src for image.

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The value isn't visible on the server because nothing is sending it to the server.

JavaScript executes on the client, *after* the server-side code has already completed executing and delivered the resulting page to the client.  Therefore you can't expect to access this value from code-behind while rendering the page.  Then in a post-back, only changes that get posted to the server from form elements are available to the server.  Therefore you can't expect to access this value from code-behind after the page is posted.

Data posted to the server is in form fields.  The entire HTML of the page isn't posted to the server.

If you want to include it in a form field, put something like a hidden field somewhere on your page:

```
<asp:Hidden runat="server" ID="imageValue" />
```

Then in your JavaScript you can also set the value of that form field:

```
opener.document.getElementById("tile_Image").src = "/Path/imageName.jpg";
opener.document.getElementById("<%=imageValue.ClientID%>").value = "/Path/imageName.jpg";
```

Comment: I tried this solution bu pop child cant find the hidden element , this is the error (he name 'imageValue' does not exist in the current context)

Comment: @AhmedEmad: Are these on different pages?  Which one is the page that's posting back to the server where you want the value to be accessible?

Comment: yes there are 2 different pages one is parent and the other is pop up child . I transfer from pop up to parent then I post back in the parent page to get the transferred src value.

Comment: @AhmedEmad: I’m struggling to picture the data flow here.  But however you do it, you need to get the value into a form element.  Maybe the form element should be on the main page?  It would need to be on whatever page is going to post to the server, and of course it can only be referenced on that page server-side.  Though you could hard-code the ClientID value if you need to reference the element on the other page.

Comment: Thanks David for your support. i listened to src change event in the parent child and when it changed i change the hidden value and it works perfectly.